# Why is echo $SHELL always showing /bin/bash?

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

There is not much to explain here. Just want to know why echo $SHELL always gives the output /bin/bash even though I switch to other shells. What do I have to do to make sure the $SHELL gives the correct shell path that I am in.

```
[root@localhost user]# echo $0
bash
[root@localhost user]# echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
[root@localhost user]# csh
[root@localhost user]# echo $0
csh
[root@localhost user]# echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
[root@localhost user]# tcsh
[root@localhost user]# echo $0
tcsh
[root@localhost user]# echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
[root@localhost user]# sh
sh-4.2# echo $0
sh
sh-4.2# echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
sh-4.2# 
[root@localhost user]# which csh
/bin/csh
[root@localhost user]# which csh
/bin/csh
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`$SHELL` is the *environment* variable that holds your *preferred shell*, not the currently running shell. It's initialised by `login` or any other application that logs you in based on the *shell* field in your user entry in the `passwd` database (your *login shell*).

That variable is used to tell applications like `xterm`, `vim`... what shell they should start for you when they start a shell. You typically change it when you want to use another shell than the one set for you in the `passwd` database.

To get a path of the current shell interpreter, on Linux, and with Bourne or csh like shells, you can do:

```
readlink "/proc/$$/exe"
```

The `rc` equivalent:

```
readlink /proc/$pid/exe
```

The `fish` equivalent:

```
set pid %self
readlink /proc/$pid/exe
```

csh/tcsh set the `$shell` variable to the path of the shell.

In Bourne-like shells, `$0` will contain the first argument that the shell received (`argv[0]`) which by convention is the name of the command being invoked (though `login` applications, again by convention make the first character a `-` to tell the shell it's a login shell and should for instance source the `.profile` or `.login` file containing your login session customisations) when not called to interpret a script or when called with `shell -c '...'` without extra arguments.

In:

```
$ bash -c 'echo "$0"'
bash
$ /bin/bash -c 'echo "$0"'
/bin/bash
```

It's my shell that calls `/bin/bash` in both cases, but in the first case with `bash` as its first argument, and in the second case with `/bin/bash`. Several shells allow passing arbitrary strings instead like:

```
$ (exec -a whatever bash -c 'echo "$0"')
whatever
```

In ksh/bash/zsh/yash.

Comment: Stéphane knows this of course, but for others, this is documented in [POSIX Base Definitions section 8.3](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_03).

Comment: This was really helpful. And it opened a new set of questions for me that were infact answered after going through POSIX base definitions section as mentioned by @StephenKitt.

Comment: Your fish equivalent has the side effect of setting a variable. I suggest `readlink /proc/(echo %self)/exe` instead.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Are you sure it does? I `strace`d `fish -c "readlink /proc/1/exe"` and `fish -c "readlink /proc/(echo %self)/exe"`. Both only issue just one clone-syscall, neither forks nor execs. But I'm tired, maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @Max looks like you're right. I thought ksh93 was the only shell to do this kind of optimisation (funnily enough, [I was making the `fish` original author aware of those ksh93 optimisations just yesterday](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/1439#issuecomment-267207007)). Thanks for making me aware of it.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas How would you do this on macOS? :)

Answer (score 2):

If the output of `echo $0` command is -bash it means that  bash was invoked as a login shell. If the output is only bash, then you are in a non-login shell.

As the `ENV` is triggered to show the desired output it is giving you `/bin/bash`

```
[root@dcconnect ~]# env | grep -i SHELL
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

Out put of `echo #SHELL` is pulled from the `ENV` variable

Answer (score 0):

The `$0` is the command that started your shell. `$SHELL` is the default shell in your system

Comment: It doesn't provide the full path. I have multiple `bash` versions installed, I need to see which one got executed