# How to display the currently running shell?

Tags: shell, zsh, macos

I've been playing around changing the default login shell of my user using a combination of `/etc/shells` and `chsh`.

This was needed, as I wanted to change from the default shell (`/bin/zsh`) to `/opt/homebrew/bin/zsh`, and the latter was compiled for arm64.

This worked fine until I accidentally deleted Brew's  `zsh`, which resulted in the terminal being unable to run shells, until I configured a custom command (e.g. `/bin/zsh`). This allowed me to reinstall Brew's `zsh`, but what surprised me was that `$SHELL` expanded to `/opt/homebrew/bin/zsh`, despite actually running `/bin/zsh`.

Now, since I can't really rely on `$SHELL`, I attempted to lookup the actual shell using `ps -Af`, but that doesn't show the full path?

```
➜  ~ ps -Af | grep -ie zsh
  502 12860 12856   0  2:08PM ttys000    0:00.94 -zsh
  502 16303 12860   0  2:09PM ttys000    0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude-dir=.idea --exclude-dir=.tox -ie zsh
  502 11291 11290   0  2:06PM ttys002    0:00.82 -zsh
```

Comment: ... see [Why is echo $SHELL always showing /bin/bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/330242/65304)

Comment: I 'd use `ps -fp$PPID`, or, if `$PPID` is not defined by your mutant shell, get the parent process's PID from `ps -fp$$`.

Comment: @waltinator That shows the `login` command, not the shell

Comment: @waltinator not the parent pid but the current pid, because the shell is the entity that will expand the variable reference, not the `ps` process.  `ps -fp $$` is correct here.